# my docker cannot use private registry(503 Service Unavailable)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I want to deploy my code to the environment of production.But when I trying to run this command:

```
  docker login -u admin -p admin123 172.xxx.x.xxx:30003
```

it returned me "503 service unavailable". 
it told me "connection refused" when I `curl http://172.xxx.x.xxx:30003` ,

it's not the first time I deploy this code and this phenomenon has never arise untill last week ,how can I do with this strange problem??

1.restart docker service
2.upgrade docker desktop(with Mac system)
but still the same!

my daemon.json :

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : [
    "172.xxx.xxx.xxx:30003",
    "127.0.0.1:5000"
  ]
}
```

and this is the context:

```
Yutongs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ yutong.liu$ docker login -u admin -p admin123 172.xxx.xxx.xxx:30003
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:30003/v2/ failed with status: 503 Service Unavailable

Yutongs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ yutong.liu$ curl http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:30003/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.xxx.xxx.xxx port 30003: Connection refused
```

Comment: this is not reachable ` curl http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:30003` ,open browser and check http://172....:3000/v2/_catalog` the Ip seems private, if you are try to access from local system use public IP of the server.

Comment: @Adiii you are right this is our company's ip address, but I've been use this private registry for a couple weeks and it returned me a "503" suddenly  XD

Answer (score 2):

The below error is a server side error,

```
503 Service Unavailable
```

Most probably your docker registry is DOWN.

Try the following steps to root cause the issue.

First check if the docker registry port is accessible or not.

```
nc -zv 172.xxx.x.xxx 30003
```

If this is successful, you can try the following cURL request to list the docker registry catalog,

```
curl http://172.xxx.x.xxx:30003/v2/_catalog
```

If this fails, it means your docker registry is down.

Please try to confirm if the docker registry is UP or DOWN and then try again.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the address first

```
docker login 172.xxx.x.xxx:30003 -u admin -p admin123
```

Comment: Yutongs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ yutong.liu$ docker login 172.xxx.xxx.xxx:30003 -u admin -p admin123 
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://172.xxx.xxx.xxx:30003/v2/ failed with status: 503 Service Unavailable